# Abort (core dumped) when deleting a dynamic 2d array after filling it using memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const char* level1[23] =
{
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X                                                               X",
"X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     X",
"X  X K                          X            D               X  X",
"X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X  X",
"X  X  X        X                  X                   XXXXX  X  X",
"X  X   XXXXX   X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXX      X  X",
"X  X        X  X        D      X  X      X   X        X  XXXXX  X",
"X  X  XXXX  X  X  XXXXXXXXXX   X     X          X  XXXX      X  X",
"X        X        X   X  E X  XXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXX  X  XXXXX  X  X",
"X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   D    X  XXK      X        X  X  X     KX  X",
"X  X     X     X KX   XXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXXXXX  X  X  X  XXXXXXDX",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  X           XXX  X            X  X  X  D   X  X",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X  XXXXX  X  X",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  X   X               X           KX  X      X  X",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  X   X  XXXXXXXXXXX  X  XXXXXXXXXXX  X  XXXXX  X",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  X   X  X     X  KX  X  X            X      X  X",
"X     X  X  X  X  X      X  X     XX  X  X     XXXXXXXXXXXXX X  X",
"X  X  X  X  X  X  X   X  X  XXXXXXXX  X  X      X     X      X  X",
"X  X  X     X     X   X  X         X  X  X   X     X         X  X",
"X  X  XXXXXXXXXXXXX   X  XXXXXXXX  X  X  X  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X",
"XS X                                                            X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};

// Player structure
struct playerinfo
{
    int x;      // X position
    int y;      // Y position
    int keys;   // Number of keys the player has
};

// Current game info structure
struct gameinfo
{
    char** board;       // The maze array
    int maxx;           // Max size of the maze array X coordinate
    int maxy;           // Max size of the maze array X coordinate
    int level;          // The level of the maze
    playerinfo player;        // Link to player data struct
};

// Initializes the dynamic array that stores the maze
char** initboard(gameinfo game)
{
    char** matrix = new char*[game.maxx];

    for (int i=0; i<game.maxx; i++)
        matrix[i] = new char[game.maxy];

    return matrix;

}

void delboard(gameinfo game)
{
    for (int i=0;i<game.maxx;i++)
        delete [] game.board[i];
    delete [] game.board;
}

int main()
{
    gameinfo game;

    game.maxx=65;
    game.maxy=23;

    game.board = initboard(game);
    memcpy(game.board,level1,sizeof(level1));

    delboard(game);
}
```

The core dump happens on the first step of "`delete [] game.board[i];`"... This only happens when the `memcpy()` line is used. What I am trying to do is copy the contents of the c-string const to a dynamic 2d array. The point is that there will be multiple levels of potentially different sizes put in as the game.board. I had initially tried `game.board[0] = "contents of line 0"` ... `game.board[23] = "contents of line 23"`, but that gave a compiler warning. Strangely this works perfectly using MinGW under Windows, but I need this to also work with Linux.

Comment: You may want to ask yourself what you're actually `memcpy`'ing when you invoke that? You're blasting over the entire set of row buffer pointers you just allocated, then attempting to `delete[]` a raft of pointers never actually allocated. Worse, you do this *twice*, each time leaking the entire set of dynamic row buffers. And this is tagged **C**.. why, exactly?

Comment: And there is no chance on earth this "works perfectly" *anywhere*. You're replacing a sequence of dynamic row buffer pointers with the sequence of `const char*` from your static table, then calling `delete[]` on those pointers. The compiler backend doesn't matter, what you're doing is UB.

Comment: This really strikes me as trying to write C code in C++. Embrace some of the c++ idioms by using some of the C++ containers and I guarantee that your life will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
memcpy(game.board,level1,sizeof(level1));
```

is wrong because:

1. It overwrites the contents of `game.board`, which is was allocated to hold an array of `char*` by the contents of `level1`.
2. You are writing over memory that you did not allocate.

You can fix the problem by changing `initboard` to copy the contents of `level1` into the right memory locations and removing the above line.

```
char** initboard(gameinfo game)
{
    char** matrix = new char*[game.maxx];

    for (int i=0; i<game.maxx; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new char[game.maxy];

        // Copy the contents of `level1[i]` to `matrix[i]`.
        strpcy(matrix[i], level1[i]);
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

**Update (Thanks to the keen eyes of @WhozCraig)**

The values you use for `game.maxx` and `game.maxy` are reversed. You need:

```
game.maxx=23; // Not 65;
game.maxy=65  // Not 23;
```

And then, you need to allocate `game.maxy+1` characters in the `initboard`.

```
        matrix[i] = new char[game.maxy+1];
```

Otherwise, there won't be enough space to hold the terminating null character in `matrix[i]`.

Comment: Note: The OP's index use is incorrect, and needs to be addressed before invoking this.  The `level1` array is 23 const pointer-to-char, each of which refers to a row 65+1 chars wide (including the terminator). The values in `game` passed to this are such that it will  allocate an array of  65 char-pointers, then for each of those, allocate a char buffer 23 elements wide, the invoke UB by copying a 65+1 length-string into 23-chars of space, invoking UB for each row in the process.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for noticing the problems and letting me know. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `char** board;` to `vector<string> board;`. Get rid of `initboard` and `delboard`, and in `main()` go:

```
game.board = vector<string>( begin(level1), end(level1) );
```

You may need includes `vector`, `string`, `iterator`. Also you can remove `maxx` and `maxy` and read them off of `board` directly.

[See it working](http://ideone.com/1jtlea) .. see how much simpler this all is?

Comment: I really like the way that works, I need to learn more about vector and how to use them in the future. I was able to get it to work without them, but it looks like it will be a better approach for any future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated this in the stack by not calling new, so there's no need to actually delete this array at the end. It will be taken care of when the code is done running! You can't delete on the stack or you'll be deleting from an address you don't have permission to access, hence the abort.

Comment: `level1` isn't _'allocated on the stack'_!